# Modifying the pixelArray of an image

Tags: java

I have a method that flips an image via its pixels. But in doing so it creates a totally new image. How could I have it modify the existing image?

```
private GImage flipHorizontal(GImage img) {

    int[][] array = img.getPixelArray();
    //width in pixels of each row of image
    int width = array[0].length;
    //loops through each row of the image
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        //in each row flip each pixel horizontally
        for (int p1 = 0; p1 < width / 2; p1++) {
            int p2 = width - p1 - 1;
            int temp = array[i][p1];
            array[i][p1] = array[i][p2];
            array[i][p2] = temp;
        }
    }
    return ( new GImage(array));
}
```

Comment: I would recommend you having a look at the `Collections.swap()`-method which would already help you simplify your code. Other than that we would need to know your `GImage` class to give any other advice.

Comment: I don't think they think that. It's more about the `new GImage(array)` probably. They want to manipulate the argument `GImage img`I'd assume. But that does require knowledge about the `GImage` class as I said.

Comment: @Ben it is a simplified version of Image class, [GImage](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/javadoc/student/acm/graphics/GImage.html).